# How to make automatic wipers more sensitive to rain (beyond control setting)?

Tags: jeep, windshield-wipers, grand-cherokee

When I asked this question: [Rain sensing wipers not clearing often enough](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/45637/rain-sensing-wipers-not-clearing-often-enough) I wasn't sure the rain sensing feature was working at all.

I've since found that they do work, they just don't clear often enough, especially in light drizzle.

The car DOES HAVE a setting to adjust sensitivity, and I've tried ALL of the settings; the wipers don't clear often enough in any of them.

Since the car is only a couple of months old, I expect any parts/labor to be under full factory warranty, so I'm thinking of having the sensor replaced.

Question: would it do any good? Is there likely to be variation between sensors, and if so, might a replacement provide the improvement I'm looking for?

As an alternative question: do these sensors have "internal" adjustments which can only be made by removing covers, using tools, etc.?

Comment: I'm surprised you don't go to the dealership and tell them you're having an issue. They are either going to get it set correctly for you, show you how to do it yourself, or fix something.

Comment: I took it to the dealer already. Problem is, if you're driving in a deluge (or hose it down, which is what they did), yeah, they wipe a little more often, proving that they work, but in light drizzle, they don't wipe until well beyond the point the windshield is impossible to see through, no matter which setting I use, and yes, I thoroughly read, fully understand, and carefully followed the manual.

Comment: Its not you, its the car. I have the same problem 2017 grand cherokee. dealer replaced sensor and did a master reset. still not working now they want to replace the windshield.